# Collection fillter not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, collection

I am trying to filter product, I having a list of product ids in an array and i want to filter product base on this ids.

I want to fetch all the product which does not have this ids (Not In) 
How can i write it. Here is my code.

```
 $ruleCreateArr = [10,15,21];

 $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

 $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','id'))
           ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin', $ruleCreateArr));
```

It seems the "nin" filter not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following its working for me:

```
$ruleCreateArr = array(10,15,21);

$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','id'))
           ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin', $ruleCreateArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. The problem is that you have a comma separating your operator and negated values. It should be `['nin' => $ruleCreateArr]` instead of `array('nin', $ruleCreateArr)`.

```
$ruleCreateArr = [10,15,21];

$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $ruleCreateArr]);
```

Also, to ensure that you remain within Magento's published coding standards for Magento 2, be sure to use short array syntax. `[]` vs. `array()`